# Is there a time limit (after committing murder) within which the Horcrux can be created?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

There have been several questions here discussing about Horcruxes. I came across [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77001/to-create-a-horcrux-do-you-have-to-kill-a-human/77026?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question that discusses about the living being (human or otherwise) that should be killed to create a Horcrux. I also [read](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23006/who-did-voldemort-kill-to-create-the-horcruxes/23007#23007) about the people Lord Voldemort killed to create his Horcruxes. And according to JKR,

> *The receptacle is prepared by dark magic to become the receptacle of a fragmented piece of soul and that that piece of soul deliberately detached from the Master Soul to act as a future safeguard or anchor to life and to safeguard against death*.

But one question still remains. Is there a specific duration (after committing murder) within which the Horcrux can be created. For example, say, good old Voldy murders a Muggle, can he create a Horcrux, say, after a month after committing the murder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## We don’t really know - it’s never mentioned if there’s a time limit.

It’s never mentioned whether there’s any sort of time limit to using a murder to create a Horcrux. However, we do know who the Dark Lord killed to make each Horcrux, and he never used an “old” murder for any of them.

> Lady Bella: Whose murders did Voldemort use to create each of the Horcruxes?
>
> J.K. Rowling: The diary – Moaning Myrtle. The cup – Hepzibah Smith, the previous owner. The locket – a Muggle tramp. Nagini – Bertha Jorkins (Voldemort could use a wand once he regained a rudimentary body, as long as the victim was subdued). The diadem – an Albanian peasant. The ring – Tom Riddle Sr. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Bloomsbury Live Chat (July 30, 2007)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)*</sup></sub>

It doesn’t prove for certain that there is a time limit, but we can at least see that there’s no known case of an old murder being used to create a Horcrux. This may simply mean, however, that the Dark Lord preferred to use fresh kills, rather than that it’s a requirement.

Comment: +1. I always understood what I've read to imply that your soul always fragmented after you committed a murder. Not aware of anything that would indicate the fragmentation was ever healed and assume that it would require active repentance, etc. In which case I'd assume the fragment was always available at a later date. Unless we assume the fragment decays and dies if not horocruxed. "This fragment best used by ____
" and all.