# Why was the Elder Wand not conflicted?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry has part of Voldemort living within himself. When Voldemort's spell rebounded when he first tried to kill Harry, part of Voldemort's soul latched on to Harry, which basically makes him and Voldemort the same person (that's why Voldemort didn't kill Harry in the forest, he essentially killed part of himself).

We know that the wands choose the wizard. Draco defeated Dumbledore and became owner of the wand, then Harry "defeated" Draco and won the allegiance of the Elder Wand. However, he did this when there was still a part of Voldemort's soul living within him.

So, when Voldemort killed Harry in the forest and the two had their final battle, why was the Elder Wand not conflicted on who its master was?

Did it not recognize the part of Voldemort that lived in Harry?

Why would the wand not answer to the both of them since Harry was still part Voldemort when he "defeated" Draco?

Comment: Also, why has this question never been asked?

Comment: First up, Harry isn't a Horcrux; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11530/how-did-harry-become-a-horcrux

Comment: Ok, I'll change the question to be referenced correctly.

Comment: Draco didn't kill Dumbledore.

Comment: Lol, whoops, misspoke there.  I'd say that this one is very similar to the last linked question.  But I'm asking why the Elder Wand wasn't conflicted.  Technically both Voldemort and Harry owned the wand.

Comment: I'd say that the entire premise of this question is flawed. Hosting part of someone's soul doesn't make you the same person, ergo the rest of the question is bunk.

Comment: It's been a month and the OP has yet to edit as he indicated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was Harry who defeated Draco, not the Voldemort's part soul. Harry was simply hosting the soul piece - he was neither in the control of the part soul (he was able to use the free will) nor he used Voldemort's skills to defeat Draco. There was no reason for the Elder Wand to give Voldemort's part soul any credit for Draco's defeat, or for that matter to consider that piece inside Harry a "real person" to choose. That's why it chose Harry and ignored Voldemort.

Comment: But Harry had the ability to speak parsletongue(spellcheck) only because of Voldemorts soul. He lost that ability after the soul was destroyed. So that soul was an active parasite.

Comment: @KharoBangdo Still, Harry had free will and he didn't use the abilities of Voldemort's soul to defeat Draco. And, this is what matters.