# Harry Potter: How did not resisting Voldemort help Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, voldemort

In Deathly Hallow, when Voldemort

> kills Harry,

Harry does not resist the spell.

When Harry was in King's Cross, Dumbledore says that it was important that Harry did not resist the spell.

**Why did Dumbledore say that? What were the implications of Harry not resisting?**

Comment: I had the impression that it was necessary in order to protect all the people back at Hogwarts from Voldemort.

Comment: I think when Harry came to know that he was meant to die by Voldemort, he felt hopeless and therefore didn't resist to die.

Comment: @mikeazo - among other reasons. I stole your comment for my answer, sorry

Comment: @DVK, no worries. I place my comment in the public domain :)

Answer (score 16):

There are three effects of Harry not resisting Voldemort. Two were certain, one is a good guess:

1. First of all, **it ensured that when Voldemort finally died, he died for good, with no Horcruxes remaining**.

   If Harry did resist Voldemort, Voldemort would not have been able to "kill" Harry - the same way Voldemort could not kill Harry in the final duel.

   The reason Voldemort lost the latter duel **was because Harry was the master of the Elder Wand** - and that was already true in the Forest scene. It had nothing to do with what happened in the forest.

   > Harry saw Voldemort’s green jet meet his own spell, saw the Elder Wand fly high, dark against the sunrise, spinning across the enchanted ceiling like the head of Nagini, spinning through the air **toward the master it would not kill**, who had come to take full possession of it at last
   >   (*Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 - The Flaw in the Plan*)

   And if Voldemort didn't "kill" Harry, he wouldn't have destroyed the last piece of his soul that was latched onto Harry, thus rendering Voldemort immortal still - so even if Harry confronted him in a duel (like he did later on) and Voldemort's body was destroyed, his soul remaint **would have again survived**, due to having had his last "Horcrux" (*yes, Harry wasn't a "real" Horcrux, but he did function as one for Voldemort's immortality purposes*).

   > “I let him kill me,” said Harry. “Didn’t I?”
   >   “You did,” said Dumbledore, nodding. “Go on!”
   >   “**So the part of his soul that was in me** . . . ”
   >   Dumbledore nodded still more enthusiastically, urging Harry onward, a broad smile of encouragement on his face.
   >   “ . . . **has it gone**?”
   >   (*Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 - King's Crosss*)

   ---
2. The second effect was that Harry, by choosing to die instead of to fight (and protect his friends from Voldemort's threats), **triggered the same kind of love protection magic that Lily's chosen sacrifice did for Harry**.

   > “You won’t be killing anyone else tonight,” said Harry as they circled, and stared into each other’s eyes, green into red. “You won’t be able to kill any of them ever again. Don’t you get it? **I was ready to die to stop you from hurting these people**—”
   >   “But you did not!”
   >   “—I meant to, and that’s what it did. **I’ve done what my mother did. They’re protected from you. Haven’t you noticed how none of the spells you put on them are binding? You can’t torture them. You can’t touch them**. You don’t learn from your mistakes, Riddle, do you?”
   >   (*Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 - The Flaw in the Plan*)

   ---
3. This one is less certain, but it's possible that not resisting is what fully proclaimed Harry as the Master of Death, which may have affected Elder Wand's allegience in the end as well.

   This is based on what Dumbledore said about the original contest between two phoenix-core wands:

   > Voldemort proceeded to attack you with a wand that shared a core with yours. And now something very strange happened, as we know. The cores reacted in a way that Lord Voldemort, who never knew that your wand was twin of his, had never expected.
   >   “**He was more afraid than you were that night, Harry. You had accepted, even embraced, the possibility of death, something Lord Voldemort has never been able to do. Your courage won, your wand overpowered his**. And in doing so, something happened between those wands, something that echoed the relationship between their masters.
   >   (*Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 - King's Cross*)

   The reason I think this was a likely side effect was because the effect #1 (killing the last "Horcrux") has already happened by the time Dumbledore and Harry spoke, yet Dumbledore used **future tense** when referring to the effects of Harry's choice:

   > “But . . . ” Harry raised his hand instinctively towards the lightning scar. It did not seem to be there. “But I should have died—I didn’t defend myself! I meant to let him kill me!”
   >   “And that,” said Dumbledore, “**will**, I think, have made all the difference.”
   >   (*Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 - King's Cross*)
4. An additional possible side effect, similar to #3, was that Harry ensured that even if he was killed in the final battle, he would easily go on, like Dumbledore himself did:

   > “I think,” said Dumbledore, “that if you choose to return, there
   >   is a chance that he may be finished for good. I cannot promise it.
   >   But I know this, Harry, that **you have less to fear from returning
   >   here than he does.**” (*DH - Ch. 35*)
   >
   > After all, **to the well-organized mind, death is but the next great
   >   adventure** (**PS**)
   >
   > “Oh yes.” Dumbledore smiled at him. “We are in King’s Cross, you say? I think that if you decided not to go back, you would be able to . . . let’s say . . . board a train.”
   >   “And where would it take me?”
   >   “On,” said Dumbledore simply. (*DH - Ch. 35*)

Comment: And yes, I'm fully aware that #1 semingly contradicts #3. #3 is a conjecture and about "further affecting" the allegience of the Elder Wand.

Comment: comprehensively done. awesome :)

Comment: I don’t think what you’re reading into that future tense is necessarily (or even probably) true. That’s a perfectly idiomatic ‘future’ tense that doesn’t actually refer to any future. It is much more likely to me that the difference Dumbledore is referring to is the fact that Harry choosing to let Voldemort kill him _means he is still master of the Elder Wand_. Dumbledore (the King’s Cross Dumbledore, at least) knows this, and knows that Harry only stands a chance at winning a duel against Voldemort that way. If Harry had not intended to die, Voldemort would have won the Elder Wand’s →

Comment: → allegiance if he’d managed to kill Harry, and the outcome of the final duel would have been **quite** another. Even if he hadn’t managed to kill a resisting Harry in the forest, he would likely have been returned to his spectral state again, and everything would almost be back to square one, except with fewer Horcruxes to get rid of before Voldemort would be mortal again.

Comment: In other words, I think another number should be added to your already excellent answer: Not resisting **ensured that Harry was able to defeat Voldemort in the final duel at all**.

Comment: About #1: Nagini was still alive, so Voldemort could not die.

Comment: @Krumia - correct. I meant in the final duel

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think your answer is very well thought-out but I have a follow-up question. Would Voldemort being master of the Elder Wand make "all the difference"? After all, Harry would still not die (sacrificial blood tether). Isn't it much more likely that Dumbledore is referring to the fact that LV will never be able to hurt anyone again? Especially b/c immediately after the quote, Harry and DD begin to discuss blood/horcruxes and only much later the wand. In fact, I think there is a direct parallel between "made all the difference" and "I meant to, and that’s what did it."...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet...Furthermore, although it is entirely possible that the two are discussing things that happened after DD's death (seeing as how the conversation is quite possibly "in Harry's head"), it seems odd that DD would mention something "making all the difference" that happened completely OUTSIDE his plan. After all, he did not plan on Harry ever being the master of the Elder Wand. What's more? Harry mentions LV's mistake in regards to the wand: "That wand still isn’t working properly for you because you murdered the wrong person."...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet....Wouldn't Harry have mentioned how his sacrifice was the latest and greatest reason why LV wasn't the EW master if it "made all the difference," rather than fixating on how he disarmed Malfoy? In sum, I think what you said is canonically correct. However, based on the fact that LV still couldn't have killed Harry AND the context of Harry/DD + Harry/LV conversations, "make all the difference"=sacrificial protection from LV.

Comment: @CCHP It would make all the difference in that the final duel at the castle at the very end would almost certainly have ended with Voldemort killing Harry, rather than himself. The sacrificial blood tether protects everyone _else_ there, but I don't think it would protect Harry himself. Without that protection, and with Voldemort Master of the Elder Wand, Harry would be a goner, and the prophecy would be realised with the other possible outcome. That would basically cement Voldemort as even more powerful and fear-instilling than before. So yes, I do think it would have made all the difference.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet 
"Precisely!" said Dumbledore. "He took your blood and rebuilt his living
body with it! Your blood in his veins, Harry, Lily’s protection inside both of you! He tethered you to life while he lives!"

Comment: @CCHP Oh, that tethering—I thought you meant Harry's own sacrificial protection. But that protection is no longer in effect, is it? If it were, Voldy’s death at the end would be impossible, basically—his backfiring Avada Kedavra would kind of create an endless catch-22 loop.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I believe it is in effect for the duration of Lord Voldemort's life (he has Lily's blood forever). I know this whole conversation stemmed from "idiomatic tenses," but I believe the present form of "while he lives" is significant in this case. It wouldn't be a loop b/c now LV has no "tether-hooks" of his own, seeing as how all the horcruxes were eliminated.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Therefore, I believe the sacrifice made all the difference by a) eliminating the horcrux (would've happened anyway)....b) protecting everyone from LV in the remainder of the battle (and the "vague future" thereafter if LV didn't die)....and c) by keeping EW custodianship w/ Harry, but that was not the intended meaning of "all the difference" b/c Harry wouldn't have died.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Let's find out for sure. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108563/was-lilys-sacrificial-protection-on-harry-still-in-effect-after-it-protected-hi

Answer (score 0):

While Voldemort doesn't know this, he accidentally

> turned Harry into a Horcrux.

That, plus the prophecy, implied that in order to defeat Voldemort for good, Harry had to die

> temporarily, thus "destroying" the second-to-last Horcrux left.

Concerning the "*not resisting*", it would have been pointless since Harry's Death was necessary. His dying without resistance also made Voldemort pretty overconfident (well, even more than he was before, anyway) and give his lengthy "surrender now, I killed your Harry without effort"-speech, which both actually encouraged the resistance *and* probably gave some additional time for

> Harry to return to life

before going on to attack those who opposed him.

Comment: [Harry was not a Horcrux](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11530/how-did-harry-become-a-horcrux/11546#11546).

Comment: @KSmarts Ok, he only was a "Horcrux". I won't modify my answer and add the afterthought of "pulling a Lilly", since [DVK's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79174/769) already does a great job at that

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Lily's sacrificial love still protected Harry.  I don't believe the Elder Wand, by itself, was strong enough to counteract that protection.

> (especially since Voldemort wasn't even the wand's true master)

By not resisting, Harry is indicating that he is at peace.

> and ready to die

By not protecting himself, the protection given to him through his mother did not apply

> allowing Harry to "die".

Comment: Lily’s sacrificial protection did not still protect Harry. It hadn’t since the end of _Goblet of Fire_.