# Did Lily know that her death would protect Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

When Voldemort came to kill Harry, Lily put herself between Voldemort and Harry unarmed. Did she do it foolishly* out of love for her child or did she know about *Sacrificial Protection* that her death could ensure the survival of her child?

*It is foolish in otherwise circumstances because logically her own death couldn't change anything.

Comment: Surprised this didn't come up when you were typing the question... http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83481/did-lily-know-that-her-death-would-save-harry?rq=1

Comment: @Skooba I am on mobile, so no suggestion. So interesting that the title wordings are almost same...