# Aren't there 8 Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter

In a memory of Dumbledore's, Tom Riddle asks Slughorn about Horcruxes. He says that he wants to split his soul into seven pieces. But Harry is the seventh and unintended one. So aren't there 8 Horcruxes in total, considering that Voldemort already split his soul into 7 pieces? Or have I made a mistake while counting?

Comment: [Harry isn't a Horcrux](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11546/5184).

Comment: @phantom42 true, but actually the one time that fact just makes things worse :)

Comment: @phantom42 "You were the seventh Horcrux, Harry, the Horcrux he never meant to make." 

Albus Dumbledore - Deathly Hallows - Page 709 - US Hardcover

Comment: @icey read the answer I linked, where Rowling specifically states otherwise.

Comment: @icey - Dumbledore Was Wrong

Comment: @DVK or at least he was oversimplifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assumed he had to keep a piece of his soul in his own body.  So while he said split it into seven pieces, one piece must stay in his body.  7-1 = 6 + Harry = 7.

Comment: so he split it to 6pieces and kept his own soul to himself until he tried to kill Harry. He gave some of his soul to Harry by the scar then? So he is half horcrux, simply a piece of Voldemort's soul is trapped inside him, but unintentedly.

Comment: Pretty much.  Of course, it could be so simple that Tom Riddle/Voldemort simply hadn't made all seven before he attacked Harry and his parents.

Answer (score 6):

*Harry isn't a Horcurx*. [JK Rowling has specifically stated this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11546/19561).

So that's why your count is off. Voldemort intended to split his soul into seven pieces (seven being a number which he believed to have special, magical properties) and make six Horcruxes out of them, keeping one piece inside his body.
But when the Avada Kedavra backfired on him, that split another piece of his soul, which got embedded in Harry's scar, unbeknownst to Voldemort.

Because he didn't know his soul had split, he did it once again to make his sixth Horcrux. So with six pieces of his soul in Horcruxes, one piece inside his body, and one piece inside Harry's scar, that's eight pieces of soul, but six Horcruxes.

1. Horcurxed in Tom Riddle's diary
2. Horcurxed in Peverell ring
3. Horcurxed in Hufflepuff cup
4. Horcurxed in Slytherin locket
5. Horcurxed in Ravenclaw diadem
6. *Embedded* in Harry's scar
7. Horcruxed in Nagini
8. Remained in Voldemort

---

> You were the seventh Horcrux, Harry, the Horcrux he never meant to make.
>
> <sup>Albus Dumbledore - Deathly Hallows - Page 709 - US Hardcover</sup>

Turns out Dumbledore was wrong.